# Why are min and max listed as sequence operations?

Tags: python

Python's documentation has a table with "[Common Sequence Operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations)" that are "supported by most sequence types". It lists for example `x in s`, `s[i]`, and `len(s)`, which the sequence can support with methods `__contains__`, `__getitem__` and `__len__`. But it also lists `min(s)` and `max(s)`, and I don't understand why. Those two work on any iterable, I don't see anything special about them in relation to sequences. There are no `__min__` and `__max__` or any other ways to truly support them, are there? And if there were, I'd expect `max(range(10**8))` to give me the result *instantly*, not take *several seconds*. Just like `10**20 in range(10**30)` does. And if `min` and `max` are just there to showcase built-in functions, I'd rather expect `reversed` to be listed, as that really has something to do with sequences (it works on every sequence, but not on every iterable).

So am I overlooking something? Or did `__min__` and `__max__` or some other way to truly support `min` and `max` exist in previous Python versions, and the table wasn't updated? Or is there some other good reason to list them there? I'm confused.

The first paragraph in that section even says:

> The `collections.abc.Sequence` ABC is provided to make it easier to correctly implement these operations on custom sequence types.

That sounds like people writing custom sequence types are somehow expected to implement them. That makes no sense to me unless there's an actual way to implement them.

Comment: `I'd expect max(range(10**8)) to give me the result instantly` it will for `xrange`, right?

Comment: @RandomDavis No, that's the point.

Comment: It seems to be a bug in the documentation. I checked `bltinmodule.c`, the place where `min_max` is defined: It unconditionally iterates over the argument.

Comment: Yes, you are overlooking that python's documentation isn't exactly the best documentation ever created of a language. But you also show that it **should** be supported through e.g. `__min__`/`__max__` methods. Until now, I didn't know that using `max(range(n))` is bad!

Comment: @L3viathan Good idea. I looked as well now, both [in master](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8394500cca56490cc347604d39ca40abcdce46c3/Python/bltinmodule.c#L1585) and in the tag corresponding to the current documentation. Nothing special regarding sequences in either, just creates an iterator and uses that.

Comment: @Wups Hmm, I think Python's documentation is pretty good. And I'm not sure `__min__`/`__max__` support would be worth it. `range` is the only built-in type I can think of where it could help a lot, and I don't think I've ever had the urge to use `min` or `max` on a `range` :-). The case of let's say `__contains__` is different, as that is of course important for `set`/`dict`. But I think `range` is the only built-in type that *naturally* could support `min`/`max`. (Some custom or 3rd-party types like [sortedcontainers](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/) could as well.)

Comment: @L3viathan For completeness: I checked there's no special-casing *before* `min_max`, either. Looks like the [entry points](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8394500cca56490cc347604d39ca40abcdce46c3/Python/bltinmodule.c#L2815-L2816) are [`builtin_min` and `builtin_max`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8394500cca56490cc347604d39ca40abcdce46c3/Python/bltinmodule.c#L1697-L1717), and they just call `min_max`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a documentation bug, the original commit for this was [made in 1998](https://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/8a306dfd9f33#l4.351). Probably the idea was to list all operations user can perform on sequences, not necessarily override them.

`reversed` on the other hand was [added in 2003](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/85c20a41dfcec04d161ad7da7260e7b94c62d228).

When the `The collections.abc.Sequence ABC is provided to make it easier to correctly implement these operations on custom sequence types` part was added either the `min`/`max` functions should have been removed from the table to prevent such confusion(as there are no dunder methods available yet to override the behaviour of these two built-in functions) or the wording should've been improved.