# Python: ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence

Tags: python

I've been trying to understand why I am getting "ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence" from my code. I've tried different things like switching list() to [] on my return statement. I am hoping someone can help me with it. Thank you in advance!

Code:

```
def fool(graph,node):
 def helper(graph, node, visited):
      visited.append(node)
      not_visited_neighbors = filter(lambda n: n not in visited, graph[node])

      if not_visited_neighbors:
           return 1 + max(map(lambda n: helper(graph, n, visited.copy()), not_visited_neighbors))
      else:
           return 1

 return helper(graph, node, [])
```

Comment: You can't use max on an empty list

Comment: @drum Yes you can.

Answer (score 2):

That's why `max` has a `default` parameter. Which gets used if the iterable is empty.

I might replace

```
if not_visited_neighbors:
     return 1 + max(map(lambda n: helper(graph, n, visited.copy()), not_visited_neighbors))
else:
     return 1
```

with (note the `default=0`)

```
return 1 + max(map(lambda n: helper(graph, n, visited.copy()), not_visited_neighbors), default=0)
```

or rather

```
return 1 + max((helper(graph, n, visited.copy())
                for n in not_visited_neighbors),
               default=0)
```

or even integrate the filtering:

```
return 1 + max((helper(graph, n, visited.copy())
                for n in graph[node]
                if n not in visited),
               default=0)
```

Using `filter`/`map` with `lambda` is an anti-pattern and indication you should probably use a generator expression instead.

Answer (score 1):

In ancient Pythons, `filter()` returned a list, but in current Pythons it returns a kind of generator instead:

```
>>> f = filter(lambda n: n & 1, range(10))
>>> f
<filter object at 0x000001C911CD53C0>
>>> bool(f)
True
>>> list(f)
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

So your `not_visited_neighbors` *always* acts "true-ish", even if it produces an empty sequence.

```
>>> f = filter(False, [])
>>> bool(f)
True
```

So apply, say, `list()` or `tuple()` to your filter result before testing it.

Comment: yes, changing from filter to list solved my issue!

Comment: Side question: `{}` is not a sequence, but `max({})` says `ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence`. Do you think it's worth opening a bug issue? (The `filter object` isn't a sequence, either, but `{}` is just a simpler example.)

Comment: I don't think so. It's generally true that when an iterable that doesn't produce anything is used in a context that requires it produce at least one thing, a complaint about an "empty sequence" is made. I expect almost everyone understands it's talking then about the (empty!) sequence of _results_ from the iterable. `max()` couldn't care less whether its argument is itself "a sequence". Whatever its argument may be, it applies the iteration protocol to it.

Comment: Hmm, if that appears in more places, that actually makes me want to fix it *more*. I like sticking to the official terminology from the docs (I also wouldn't call the `filter` object a generator or say "true-ish" instead of true, maybe I asked the wrong person ;-). I think `max() arg is empty` would be better, I don't see why it even says "sequence". Was "sequence" once upon a time Python's word for "iterable"? That might also explain why `min`/`max` are [oddly listed as sequence operations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63959241/12671057).

Comment: The "official" Python word for how values act in a Boolean context is "truthiness". Too cute for me, so I say "true-ish". It's not, e.g., true that a filter object "is true". It is true that it acts the same way `True` acts when used in a Boolean context. Older versions of Python indeed had no concept at all of "iterable". For the rest, I have no interest in arguing about it. Feel free to open an issue report, if you like. Already gave my take.

Comment: Ugh... "truthiness"... it was fun when Colbert said that, but in Python context I despise that word. How is that the "official" Python word? As far as I know, it [doesn't appear in the docs at all](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Adocs.python.org+%22truthiness%22) and the actual official term is [truth value](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing). And true/false *are* the words the docs use all over the place, for example in that truth value section and the Boolean Operations section right below it which says things like "if x is false, then y, else x".

Comment: Use Google: "site:mail.python.org truthiness"

Comment: I don't think arbitrary people talking on a mailing list is "official".

Comment: You're absolutely right about that.